# How to see diff between working directory and staging index?

Tags: git, git-diff

We can see difference between **repository and working directory** with:

```
git diff
```

We can see difference between **repository and staging index** with:

```
git diff --staged
```

But how do we see difference between **working directory and staging index**?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Actually, `git diff` is between index and working tree.  It just so happens that until you have staged changes to the index (with `git add`) that its contents will be identical to the `HEAD` commit.

`git diff HEAD` is between repo and working tree.

See [365git.tumblr.com post](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/3464927214/getting-a-diff-between-the-working-tree-and-other):

[image: git diffs]

Comment: I don't understand this because right now I have "file.txt" in repository with content "1". Then I modify that file in my working directory to have content "12" but WITHOUT adding it to staging index. Then when I enter "git diff" I DO get difference shown in console. So there is nothing in staging index but I still get the difference between repository and working directory. I am really confused now.

Comment: @matori82 by default, index is equal to repo. Index differs from repo only when you start adding file to it.

Comment: Ah... I didn't know that. Guess I will have to dive more into git internals to get information like this... Thank you.

Comment: However, the logic of this command seems to be even more complex. Eg. if I have one file in index and one modified file in working directory, when I do the "git diff" then difference is shown for the file in working directory but the difference for file in staging index is not shown at all! This is really really confusing now...

Comment: @matori82 That is expected: the goal of `git diff` is, by default,to show what has not yet been tracked (added to the index or committed). What you had to the index is no longer shown by default, because you already reviewed it and decided to make it part of the next commit.

Comment: it looks like I am missing some key understanding of the staging index concept in git. In my simple mind index is just temporary location where files are stored before commit. Once I do commit this index area is emptied and disconnected from the repository. You said above "by default, index is equal to repo. Index differs from repo only when you start adding file to it." which I don't understand. Could you please point me to some online resource that has good explanation of this sentence? Thank you.

Comment: @matori82 sure: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3690796/6309. When you just committed, the index is equal to the repo. Then you start to `git add` files (the index differs from the repo, and `git diff` will only show you the files or part of files which have *not* been added to the index). Then you commit, and the index is again equals to the repo.

Comment: @matori82 HEAD and index are both snapshot of a working tree. The file shown in green in `git status` are the differences between HEAD and the index (which you can get with `git diff --cached` in diff format), the file shown in red are the differences between the actual working tree and the index

Answer (score 13):

- **git diff**          - Compare working area to index.
- **git diff --staged** - Compare stage area to repository.
- **git diff HEAD**     - Compare working area to repository

To illustrate that, I changed a file with “Name Staged” text and than I added it (git add .). After that, I changed the file again, now I replaced the text to “Name Working Area” and than I run the follow commands:

[image]

Now you can see clearly how it works. Pretty cool, right?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @VonC's accepted answer, instead of `git diff HEAD` you can also write:

```
git difftool --dir-diff --no-prompt HEAD
```

This will open **a directory diff showing the differences between your working tree and the repo**. From there it's pretty easy to view changes to individual files (e.g. when using a tool like Beyond Compare with its tabbed UI).