# How to diff between Working Directory and Staging Area?

Tags: git

As per my [understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29319403/1772898) `git diff` is used to compare files between Working Directory and Staging Area. However, If I have no staged changes in the Staging Area, the same command `git diff` compare files between Working Directory and HEAD.

Why the same command (`git diff`) is giving two different outputs?

How do I actually diff between Working Directory and Staging Area?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51364288/446792 doesn't this answer you questions?

Comment: do you mean `git diff --cached` ?

Comment: @lucascavalcante `git diff --staged` or `git diff --cached` compare Staging Area with HEAD. It does not compare Working Directory with HEAD.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3686452/86072

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between git HEAD and the current project state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293607/difference-between-git-head-and-the-current-project-state)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, one point needs clarification :

In `git`, when one talks about files in "the staging area" or "the index", they actually refer to :

- the files as they are in the `HEAD` commit,
- plus the potential `git add`ed modifications.

So the meaning of "there are no modifications in the staging area" is :
"the staging area is the same as `HEAD`".

---

With that in mind, you can re-read [the diagram posted by VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29319403/86072) :

- `git diff` will display the differences between the worktree and the staging area (the index) ;
- when there are no extra modifications staged, "the index" is the same as `HEAD` -- as a consequence, `git diff` will indeed show the difference between `HEAD` and your worktree ;
- the command that will always show you "the difference between `HEAD` and your worktree" (and disregard the index) is : `git diff HEAD`

Comment: I just found that If you have no staged changes, `git diff` will show Working Directory Vs HEAD. Please let me know if you find something different.

Comment: @blueray : I think one point needs to be clarified : when one talks about "the index" or "staged files" in git, it actually means : the files as they are in the `HEAD` commit, plus the modifications that have been `git add`ed. So "no modifications staged" is the same as "the index is equal to `HEAD`". Does this shed some new light on the diagram you linked ?